# Wagtail Page Privacy 'Private, accessible to users in specific groups' as SAAS separation

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Scenario: A User registers to my Wagtail site. This creates a Group, and a Page. This page wil be set Private 'Private, accessible to users in specific groups' The just created group will be set.
The user invites people to the group, and shares pages as childpages of the just created root-page, so only group members can acces it.
Would this scale? For like, hopefully, thousands of groups? Is this a way to separate content for a SAAS setup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work - I can't think of any issues that would prevent that approach from scaling to thousands of groups.

However, be aware that Wagtail doesn't currently provide complete isolation between sub-sites on the same Wagtail installation - users will still be able to see pages from other groups when they're choosing a page to link to.

Comment: Thanks gasman for your answer. With 'sub-sites on the same wagtail installation' you refer to the 'Site' functionality, or the private root pages?

Comment: Private root pages.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I haven't even thought about adding those Private pages in the upper root. If I do, it indeed opens the ability to use the Site functionality of Wagtail. Great CMS!